# Оптимизация кода, печатающего последовательность A349597

Tags: python, оптимизация, числовые-последовательности

Последовательность A349597 задаётся по следующему правилу:

> a(n) is the sum of digits of a(n-1)! with a(1) = 3.

Я попытался написать программу:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)

def sum_of_digits(n):
    return sum(int(digit) for digit in str(n))

def a(n, a_prev=3):
    if n == 1:
        return a_prev
    else:
        return a(n-1, sum_of_digits(factorial(a_prev)))

for i in range (1, 10):
    print(a(i))
```

Эта программа сначала выдаёт числа:

> 3 6 9 27 108 666 6327

Однако затем начинает глючить:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file0.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(a(i))   File "file0.py", line 14, in a
    return a(n-1, sum_of_digits(factorial(a_prev)))
  File "file0.py", line 14, in a
    return a(n-1, sum_of_digits(factorial(a_prev)))
  File "file0.py", line 14, in a
    return a(n-1, sum_of_digits(factorial(a_prev)))
    [Previous line repeated 4 more times]
  File "file0.py", line 5, in factorial
    return n * factorial(n-1)
  File "file0.py", line 5, in factorial
    return n * factorial(n-1)   File "file0.py", line 5, in factorial
    return n * factorial(n-1)
    [Previous line repeated 988 more times]
  File "file0.py", line 2, in factorial
    if n == 1:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как исправить такое положение.

Answer (score 0):

Ой, кажется, у меня уже получилось?

```
import sys

def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        result *= i
    return result

def sum_of_digits(n):
    return sum(int(digit) for digit in str(n))

def a(n, a_prev=3):
    result = a_prev
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        result = sum_of_digits(factorial(result))
    return result

sys.setrecursionlimit(1000)

for i in range(1, 10):
    print(a(i))
```